# Number of k consecutive 1's subsequences in a binary string.

Tags: probability, expected-value

> > Say a sequence $\{X_1, X_2,\ldots ,X_n\}$ is given, where $X_p$ is either one or zero ($0 < p < n$) with 
> >     probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each. Let $N_k$ be the number of consecutive  1's subsequences of length k in $\{X_1, X_2,\ldots ,X_n\}$,what is $\Bbb E[N_k]$?
> >
> > Example: in the sequence $1110011$ we have $N_2=3.$

Comment: Hint: use linearity.  if $i\in \{1,\cdots, n-(k-1)\}$ then $i$ can be the start of a consecutive sequence of $k$ $1's$ so let $X_i$ be the indicator value of that event and work from there.

Comment: If there is a subsequence of $N_{k+2}$, for instance, does that contain 3 $N_k$ sequences, 1, or none?  In other words does it have to be exactly k long to count?

Comment: It does not have to be exactly k,I added an example for clearance.@player100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$N_k=\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1}X_iX_{i+1}\ldots X_{i+k-1}.$ Hence $E(N_k)=E(\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1}X_iX_{i+1}\ldots X_{i+k-1})=(n-k+1)E(X_1,X_2\ldots X_k)=\frac{n-k+1}{2^k}$ if we have independence among $X_i$'s.

Comment: add on to the question:What is the probability of not having a sequence of length $\frac{1}{2}\log_2n$?